# Realistic Paper Tear

Tags: modeling, animation, shaders, photorealism

I am trying to make a photorealistic paper tear. I already have the correct animation. I used two curves to bend a sheet of paper (a plane) to tear into 2 halves. To make the tear lines I subdivided the plane and at the tear line I used random transform to shift the vertices, then split the plane into 2 objects.

This does not look very realistic. There are two issues: the shader, and the geometry.

Geometry:
If you grab a piece of paper and tear it, you will notice that at the tear line that there are actually multiple layers of paper and not just one. There are also some "hairs" that appear inside the tear line.

Shader:
Paper isn't actually a solid color, it is slightly translucent but there is some variation of translucency. My attempts with noise textures don't look right.

I could probably work out the shader, but I am completely stumped when it comes to the geometry of the tear.

Comment: Could you add some screenshots of what you already achieved?

Comment: @bstnhnsl its nothing worth showing, just two bent planes with a jagged edge.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=03o5i6SFNgs

Comment: Hello :). Wouldn't it be easier to just use an image texture of a real paper tear? And since paper is just about 0,06 mm thick, solidify modifier should work well enough.

Comment: @JachymMichal yes, however, I would like this to be entirely procedural.